# Can't Find Ubuntu Kernel Configuration

Tags: linux, kernel

Everyone says the original configuration for your kernel should be in /boot/config-`uname -r` but the only thing I see is memtest86+.bin.  Any suggestions?  I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and kernel 2.6.32.16-linode28.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in /proc/config.gz.  If you need to extract your kernel's configuration use

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > /usr/src/linux/.config
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Linode uses Xen.  So your VPS is what's called a DomU. So it's possible that they are keeping the kernels in the Dom0, the privileged domain used for managing the virtual machines.  If you contact Linode support I'm sure they can verify that for you.